# ng-repeat with input text box track by $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing an application where a div hoolds datepicker, 2 timepicker and a input text box. and i have a checkbox outside of div. Each time when i check a checkbox one div of date location will add. My application works fine except my input box value. ng-model is not holding the text-box value

```
<div class="dateContainer"  ng-repeat="selecting in selects track by $index">
  <div class="datePicker">  
    <button bs-datepicker>
      --- some code
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="timePicker">  
    <button bs-timePicker>
      --- some code
    </button>
  </div>
  <label class="configLocation" for="configLoc">Location</label>
  <input class = "form-control"type="text" ng-change ="DateArr($index)"  style="font-weight: normal;"name ="configLocation" class="configLocation"  ng-model = "selects[$index].configLoc" />
</div>
```

I kept my model name selects[$index].configLoc since i am trying to save based on each index value.

My controller-
I am initializing $scope.selects like below.

```
$scope.selects = [{commDate : null,commEtime: null,commStime: null,configLoc: ''}];
```

When i call DateArr($index) on change event am unable to get the entered value
$scope.selects[0].configLoc ?? value always showing ''. why??

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: First thing you dont need to initialise  $scope.selects like that just keep it like this $scope.selects ={}; rest your html can handle and you will have right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use $index in ng-repeat or ng-model ... 
just change :

```
ng-repeat="selecting in selects"
  (or)
ng-model="selecting.configLoc"
```

Answer (score 0):

For each ng-repeat a new scope is created with the repeated item, i.e. selecting.

```
ng-model = "selects[$index].configLoc"
```

becomes

```
ng-model = "selecting.configLoc"
```